# Deleting "system protected" file in Windows 10

Tags: windows, filesystems

I am trying to delete the folder `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\.atom`, but my permissions are messed up. It says I require permissions from myself. Anyway to remove the folder?

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I still can't delete the the folder. The file `update.exe` is stopping me. It seems I can't change permissions on the `update.exe` file. I have tried to delete it using the `del /f /a:s update.exe` command. I was in the `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\local\atom` folder at the time of executing the command. When I attempt this, I get the message `Access is denied`. Yes, I launched command prompt in administrator mode.

Comment: Check if it is running in background. Try command:: `takeown /f update.exe && icacls update.exe /grant Everyone:f`

Comment: I tried the command. But got `ERROR: The system can not find the file specified`

Comment: Whaaaat? Do you know anything about CMD? Change the update.exe with it's full path.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. As your question, I am used to using bash